# Is it possible to get URL from a random Gist?

Tags: python, github, gist

I'm currently working on a project where I need to get the raw file from **random Gists files**.

I already figured out how to take the [raw file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798320/how-do-i-get-source-code-out-of-a-gist) from a Gist, and I already read how the [search mechanisms](https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-code) from Gist works, but I cannot figure out how do I **randomly generate an URL** from an existing Gist repo. My final goal is to use a Python script to generate random URLs.

As I understand the Gists are organized as:

`https://gist.github.com/`**`{user}`**/**`{repo_code}`**

Is there a way to do this randomly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the [Github Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/) (sections like [this one](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users) on users are probably relevant).